# Specify Request Desktop Site Location

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

How do I specify the location of the 'Request desktop site' option.

Currently, I have this code running

```
var detector = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent);
    if(detector.mobile() != null || detector.phone() != null || detector.tablet() != null){
        document.location = '/mobile/login';
    }
```

It works at login page, but when I navigate directly to the /mobile/signup, and I click request desktop site, it returns the mobile signup site not the desktop.

On the other hand,

If I go to /desktop/signup, it redirects me to the /mobile/signup
Which is good and I can request desktop site redirecting me to /desktop/signup, **but** if I go directly to /mobile/signup I cannot request desktop site.

I am currently using mobile-detect.js

Comment: Have you checked what those function calls in the `if` condition return?

Comment: can you share the code for the redirect to the desktop site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two different folders named `desktop` and `mobile` then add below script in files present at `desktop` folder:

```
var detector = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent);
    if(detector.mobile() != null || detector.phone() != null || detector.tablet() != null){
        var currentLocation = window.location.href;

       if (currentLocation.indexOf("desktop") > -1){
       document.location.href = currentLocation.replace("desktop","mobile");}
    }
```

construct similar script and add to files present in `mobile` folder.